# Create and Writing into a .tempo file using PowerShell Script with variables passed, a specific format

Tags: exe, powershell-3.0

I would like to create a **abcd.tempo** file using powershell and want to add the content  in the below format :

Startdate:12/06/2020

ParamVar2:RISPA

ParamVar3:MLPL

CNTRY=USA

the above is the targeted format , i need to insert into the abcd.tempo file.
Startdate is a variable used and similar to this, other variables as well.

what i meant,Startdate, ParamVar2   , ParamVar3, CNTRY are hardcoded labels and these parameters would be filled with the dynamic values fetched from other code block in my  same powershell  file.

At present, am able to create a new  abcd.tempo file using

`new-item -filepath "$myfilepath2createFile"   -itemtype File`
and i added some dummy content inside that. but
am not able understand how can i create the similar structure , written above.

2. Another requirement is to call a EXE file from this powershell script and pass anotehr 4 parameters to the  EXE
   Though i used

   `Start-Process -FilePath $script:testingexeFile`

   am stuck at how to pass the 4 parameters to this EXE